# check if char[] contains only one letter and one int

Tags: java, char

I have no idea how to check if `char[]` contains only one letter (a or b) on the first position and only one int (0-8) on the second position. for example `a2`, `b2`

I have some this, but I do not know, what should be instead of digital `+=1`;

```
private boolean isStringValidFormat(String s) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if (s == null) return false;

    int digitCounter = 0;

    char first = s.charAt(0);
    char second = s.charAt(1);

    if (first == 'a' || first == 'b') {
        if (second >= 0 && second <= '8') {
            digitCounter +=1;
        }
    }

    ret = digitCounter == 2; //only two position
    return ret;
}




` public char[] readFormat() {
    char[] ret = null;
    while (ret == null) {
        String s = this.readString();
        if (isStringValidFormat(s)) {
            ret = s.toCharArray();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Values must be between 'a0 - a8' and 'b0 - b8'");
        }
    }
    return new char[0];
}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would test for `null` and that there are two characters in the `String`. Then you can use a simple `boolean` check to test if `first` is `a` **or** `b` **and** the `second` is between `0` and `8` inclusive. Like,

```
private boolean isStringValidFormat(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() != 2) {
        return false;
    }
    char first = s.charAt(0);
    char second = s.charAt(1);
    return (first == 'a' || first == 'b') && (second >= '0' && second <= '8');
}
```

Comment: Just to add more info for OP, the order on `if (s == null || s.length() != 2)` matters since `length()` throws NPE for `null`, so make sure you keep the null check first.

Answer (score 1):

For a well understood pattern, use Regex:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[ab][0-8]$")

public boolean isStringValidFormat(String input) {
    if (input != null) {
        return pattern.matcher(input).matches();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This currently does not handle `null`, also in my opinion, there is not really a reason to use a `static` field for the pattern, just place it inside the method (I assume you are doing that to optimize it so it only compiles one time, but I don't think that is necessary personally, but I guess its a personal choice).

Comment: @Nexevis Compiling a pattern takes time. I think placing the pattern as a `static final` variable is higly opinion based, but I'd do so too

Comment: It's programmatically cheaper to build the pattern up front and keep a reference to it.

Comment: @codeflush.dev I would only move it outside of the method if it was shown to actually be causing a considerable slowdown on the program and the speed needs to be improved because I prioritize cleaner code, but I agree this is opinion based.

Comment: I would firmly place it in opinion.  To me, "clean" would be to externalize all the regex patterns to a utility class so they're all together.  In a larger program, it's all too easy to keep re-inventing regex if it's hidden inside individual class methods.  I think it's better to form good habits, even for smaller programs.